# ValueError: Expected object or value - read_json method pandas

Tags: json, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to read in a large .json file into a pandas dataframe on google colab. I have read similar problems on here as well as the api for read_json method to no avail. I feel that the `orient='records'` arg should work for my json. Any help would be appreciated.

My code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_json('/content/data/events_World_Cup.json', orient='records')
```

The error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/json/_json.py in _parse_no_numpy(self)
   1157         else:
   1158             self.obj = DataFrame(
-> 1159                 loads(json, precise_float=self.precise_float), dtype=None
   1160             )
   1161 

ValueError: Expected object or value
```

An element of my json file:

```
[
    {"eventId": 8, 
     "subEventName": "Simple pass", 
     "tags": [{"id": 1801}], 
     "playerId": 122671, 
     "positions": [{"y": 50, "x": 50}, {"y": 53, "x": 35}], 
     "matchId": 2057954, 
     "eventName": "Pass", 
     "teamId": 16521, 
     "matchPeriod": "1H", 
     "eventSec": 1.6562140000000003, 
     "subEventId": 85, 
     "id": 258612104
     }
.
.
.
]
```

The entire json file can be found here:
https://figshare.com/articles/dataset/Events/7770599?backTo=/collections/Soccer_match_event_dataset/4415000

I am using the events_World_Cup.json to start off given its size.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me;

```
pd.read_json('events_World_Cup.json', orient='records')
```

Pandas version: `1.3.4`

Python version: `3.10.0`

Can you please check your pandas version?

Comment: my pandas version on colab is 1.3.5 and my python version is 3.7.12. Working on upgrading python version in colab. Would the python version really make that big of a difference?

Comment: I dont think its because of python version. I've tried it on local jupyter maybe its because of colab lib dependencies.

Comment: For some reason it worked when I placed the json file as locally as possible. It seems the problem was with the path, even though I had the correct path to it.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that this error is thrown even when the file is not found. That error message is extremely misleading. What I had to do was:

`drive.mount('/content/drive')`

then,

```
WC_events = pd.read_json('/content/drive/MyDrive/colab_notebooks/491_research/events_World_Cup.json', orient='records')
```

and this worked.